# SharePoint List Item Update - Concurrency Using REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm using REST API for updating the SharePoint list item (Counter). In my code on form load I'm fetching the count from list and increment to 1 & on submit button click I'm updating the value of count. Till here I have achieved.

Problem arises , If two users submit the form at the same time, then counter value is incremented by 1 instead to 2 in the list.

Checked with etags . But I found that during post if etag doesn't match with get request etag then error will be thrown.

Is there way to achieve this functionality using REST API also incrementing the counter properly , if more than 3-4 users submit the form ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't expose a transaction manager such that you could group multiple rest operations in one atomic transaction.